# How to get optimization level (O0,O1,O2 etc) from a llvm pass?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I am writing a llvm pass. I want to bail out my pass if optimization level is O0 or O1. I am not able to find the right API to query the optimization level from a function pass. I tried to search this option in codebase and doc, but could not locate one.

Comment: The current code is the other way around — O1 etc. is defined as a list of passes. You can't change that list in the pass, you have to change O1. I can't remember the name of that function, but you can find it. It's in a file that #includes a *massive* number of pass .h files.

Comment: I dont want to change the optimization level in the code. I just want to read the value, do something default. I have seend "getOptLevel()" in TargetMachine class, not sure if it is the right API.

Comment: It's not. What you want is the OptimizationLevel used in [PassBuilder.h](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/llvm/include/llvm/Passes/PassBuilder.h) and while I haven't looked thoroughly at that in a while, that still seems to be used only during construction of the list of passes and is not available to objects in the list.